# Showing a dynamic grid view from SQL select statement

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, data-binding, webforms

On my webform for ASP.Net I display a table from SQL Server. However, what I would like to do is offer the user of the web page the ability to check some boxes and only show those particular columns once I refresh the page.

Here is the aspx html:

```
<div style="width: 1250px; height: 300px; overflow: auto">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" HeaderStyle-BackColor="Black" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="Silver" RowStyle-BackColor="#EEEEEE" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="White" 
        AlternatingRowStyle-ForeColor="#000" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns ="false" AllowPaging="false" OnPageIndexChanging="OnPageIndexChanging" AllowSorting="True">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField ="WeekEndingDate" HeaderText="Week Ending Date" ItemStyle-Width="150px" dataformatstring="{0:MM-dd-yyyy}" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField ="Week_Number" HeaderText="Week Number" ItemStyle-Width="150px" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField ="Class" HeaderText="Class" ItemStyle-Width="150px" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField ="Animal" HeaderText="Animal" ItemStyle-Width="150px" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField ="North_Island" HeaderText="North Island" ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataFormatString="{0:F2}" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField ="South_Island" HeaderText="South Island" ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataFormatString="{0:F2}" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField ="New_Zealand" HeaderText="New Zealand" ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataFormatString="{0:F2}" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

Here is the bindgrid method:

```
private void BindGrid()
    {
        string strConnString = "server= N-1077; Trusted_Connection=yes; database=Slaughter; connection timeout=30";
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT CONVERT(date, Week_Ending_Date) AS WeekEndingDate," + 
                "Week_Number, Class, North_Island = CAST(North_Island as float), South_Island = CAST(South_Island as float)," +
                "(CAST(North_Island as float)) + (CAST(South_Island as float)) AS New_Zealand," +
                "Animal = (CASE WHEN Class = 'Sheep' OR Class = 'Lamb' THEN 'Ovine' WHEN Class = 'Calf' THEN 'Calf' ELSE 'Bovine' END)" +
                "FROM Slaughter ORDER BY WeekEndingDate DESC"))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                    {
                        sda.Fill(dt);
                        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                        GridView1.DataBind();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there a simple way to select particular columns and only show these? i.e. if they were only interested in week_number, class and south_island it would only display the data for those three columns? I don't mind building the SQL query based on the user inputs but it's how I change the boundfield Datafields to reflect on those columns that were selected in that query.

Comment: asp.BoundField has Visible property. Set it to false and the column will become hidden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way of doing it with the Visible property.

```
protected void RefreshSQLDisplay(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (BoundField col in GridView1.Columns)
    {
        if (col.DataField == "WeekEndingDate")
        {
            col.Visible = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The disadvantage is that the columns will be still in memory and the sql query will retrieve the data. So it's better to change the sql query after all for performance reasons.

**Update:** I edited the code as you asked

Comment: I'm trying this but getting an error saying no extension method 'DataField' accepting first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). I have: using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

Comment: I didn't compile the code. I updated the answer with your code.

Comment: Good enough for me you gave me the answer it just wasn't quite working in that format.